# Why am i getting unexpected CALL_START on npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, npm

I'm running into an issue trying to start my server.js node script. This complain seems to come from

```
./node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/helper.js:197:13
```

it says unexpected CALL_START which is somehow indicating my start script is breaking. I do have a couple of coffee script linked to it which are all perfectly fine since i just pulled it off github and have not tampered with it. It is hard to tell where the problem is coming from or what it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take the coffeescript you pulled from github and validate it using an online tool. It could be old code and doesn't compile with the latest version. Posting the code would help too...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I somehow messed up my code...and i have fixed it. Funny how the error message had nothing to do with the actual problem. Thanks anyways :)